# Compile PHP 7 from source

Tags: php, ubuntu, compilation

I am trying to compile PHP7 from source. Also, every other libraries which PHP depends on are build from source and they are located in custom directory.(This is important not to be advised to download the development packages!!! ) I use Ubunti 14.04.

So basically the configuration is simple

```
sudo ldconfig $HOME/programs/pcre/lib \
$HOME/programs/zlib/lib \
$HOME/programs/bzip2/lib \
$HOME/programs/libpng/lib \
$HOME/programs/libjpeg/lib \
$HOME/programs/libmcrypt/lib \
$HOME/programs/mhash/lib \
$HOME/programs/libxslt/lib \
$HOME/programs/libxml2/lib \
$HOME/programs/gettext/lib \
$HOME/programs/zlib/lib \
$HOME/programs/iconv/lib \
$HOME/programs/postgresql/lib \
$HOME/programs/curl/lib \
$HOME/programs/zlib/lib


CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/programs/zlib/include \
-I$HOME/programs/bzip2/include \
-I$HOME/programs/libpng/include \
-I$HOME/programs/libjpeg/include \
-I$HOME/programs/libmcrypt/include \
-I$HOME/programs/mhash/include \
-I$HOME/programs/libxslt/include \
-I$HOME/programs/libxml2/include \
-I$HOME/programs/gettext/include \
-I$HOME/programs/zlib/include \
-I$HOME/programs/iconv/include \
-I$HOME/programs/postgresql/include \
-I$HOME/programs/curl/include \
-I$HOME/programs/zlib/include"

./configure --prefix=$HOME/programs/php \
--enable-fpm \
--with-fpm-user=fpmu \
--with-fpm-group=fpmg \
--with-libxml-dir=shared,$HOME/programs/libxml2 \
--with-pcre-regex=$HOME/programs/pcre \
--with-zlib=$HOME/programs/zlib \
--with-config-file-path=$HOME/programs/php/config \
--with-openssl=$HOME/programs/openssl \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-bz2=$HOME/programs/bzip2 \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--with-gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-gd-jis-conv \
--with-png-dir=$HOME/programs/libpng \
--with-jpeg-dir=shared,$HOME/programs/libjpeg \
--with-mcrypt=shared,$HOME/programs/libmcrypt \
--with-mhash=shared,$HOME/programs/mhash \
--with-xsl=shared,$HOME/programs/libxslt \
--with-sqlite3=no \
--with-pdo-sqlite=no \
--with-gettext=shared,$HOME/programs/gettext \
--with-iconv-dir=shared,$HOME/programs/iconv \
--with-pgsql=shared,$HOME/programs/postgresql \
--with-pdo-pgsql=$HOME/programs/postgresql/bin \
--with-curl=$HOME/programs/curl \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-opcache-file \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip \
--enable-phar \
--enable-re2c-cgoto \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-shmop
```

When I run the config command the first error that occured was that xml2-config file was not found (but it's right on his place, healthy and smiling to me). I tried impressive variety of combinations but the error did not disappear. Finally I disabled libxml. But then another error occurred. **jpeglib.h not found.** So Basically I think The compiler does not receive the correct libraries and headers I am supplying.

I will be thankful somebody to explain why is this happening and how to solve the problem. Also I tried to build PHP5.6.12. Same 'success'.

P.S. I tried to copy xml2-config in one of the default libraries or /usr/local/bin and the xml error did not occurred anymore but then I get stuck again with the libjpeg.h ....

Comment: I build libjpeg from source and attempted to configure PHP and am not getting the same error you are.  What is the directory structure within `$HOME/programs/libjpeg`?

Comment: Hello drew010. The structure is: bin/ include/ lib/ share/

Comment: Alkso @drew010 the version is 9a (jpegsrs.v9a.tar.gz) if is important

Comment: That's what I have too.  I built jpeg 9a.  In `include/` I have `jconfig.h  jerror.h  jmorecfg.h  jpeglib.h` and in `lib/` I have `libjpeg.a  libjpeg.la  libjpeg.so  libjpeg.so.9  libjpeg.so.9.1.0`  My PHP configure switch included `--with-jpeg=shared,/opt/php7/programs/libjpeg`  I was building PHP 7 beta3

Comment: @drew010 For your build did you use some environment variables. Like  CPPFLAGS  LDFLAGS or anything else. For the dynamic linking during the build i use ldconfig  and CPPFLAGS for including the headers. That is all.

Comment: I did not - I'm not sure they are really necessary.  Maybe try without that and see if it works?  The CPPFLAGS for include path may be affecting where it is finding the headers.

Answer (score 0):

for myself I have done `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg-progs` and then it has worked on Ubuntu 14.04.

I did it on two of my computers and both works!

:-)